# AWS Cloudwatch filter log events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I've json logs in AWS Cloudwatch. Below is the example format of the log:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2020-01-10T06:49:47.180+00:00",
    "message": "Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext",
    "logger_name": "org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext",
    "thread_name": "main",
    "level": "INFO",
    "level_value": 20000,
    "application": "test"
}
```

I want to filter my logs based on timestamp field but as timestamp field contains character "@", I am not able to filter it. Is it possible to filter with such keys?

I am using below syntax to filter the fields:

**{$.level = "INFO"}** - to filter based on level field value.

**{$.@timestamp = *}** - to filter based on timestamp field value.

Comment: whats the filter command are you using. are you using cli

Comment: {$.@timestamp = *} .. No i am doing it through console.